# Ember.JS: Your server returned a hash with the key id but you have no mapping for it

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, sails.js

Consider this Ember JS Model:

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend({
    firstName: DS.attr('string')
});
```

I am able to successfully save the model on the server using this as an XHR request:

```
{ 
   "user": {
     "first_name":"dude"
   }
}
```

but for some reason it gives me an error while returning this XHR response:

```
{
    "id":1,
    "user":{
        "first_name":"dude"
    },
    "createdAt":"2013-04-12T03:13:52.382Z",
    "updatedAt":"2013-04-12T03:13:52.382Z"
}
```

The error says: ***Your server returned a hash with the key id but you have no mapping for it***

Ember expects the output to look like:

```
{ 
   "user": {
     "id":1,
     "first_name":"dude",
     "createdAt":"2013-04-12T03:13:52.382Z",
     "updatedAt":"2013-04-12T03:13:52.382Z"
   }
}
```

I think the problem lies in the request itself, but I'm not sure.
Note that I'm using the Sails API as my backend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a controller to marshal the data format to whatever you need-- but this raises an interesting question about adding support for different front-end conventions to the API blueprints.  Right now, Sails.js API blueprints support Backbone out of the box, but obviously that doesn't do you a lot of good if you're using Ember :)  I created an issue for that here https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/317.

Here's a hacky example of how you'd use a custom controller to send back data in this format using Sails today:

```
// api/controllers/UserController.js
module.exports = {

  // Create action: (e.g. using default route, you'd POST to /user/create)
  create: function (req,res) {
    // Grab attributes from request using Ember conventions
    var newAttributes = req.param('user');

    // Create the user object in the datastore
    User.create(newAttributes, function (err, newUser) {
      // If there was an error, handle it
      if (err) return res.send(err,500);

      // Respond with the user object using Ember conventions
      res.json({
         user: newUser
      });
    });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

That's a weirdly formatted JSON response. Do you have access to the server?
Ember expects the response as a a hash with root keys

```
{ 
   "user": {
     "id":1,
     "first_name":"dude",
     "createdAt":"2013-04-12T03:13:52.382Z",
     "updatedAt":"2013-04-12T03:13:52.382Z"
   }
}
```

Comment: Actually I think I know the problem. Ember sends this { 
   "user": {
     "first_name":"dude"
   }
}. That's why the response is messed up. Is there a way to fix the way I send this XHR payload data?

Comment: It is possible, but it is still quite difficult with Ember Data in it's current form, I have no experience with Sails, but if you have any way of modifying the server API, that's the better way to go. What Ember expects is considered best practice these days anyway.

Comment: I modified the server and I kind of solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Also with Grape you can do: `present MyModel.find(params[:id]), with: MyModel::Entity, root: 'my_model'`.